# Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (1 received)

Tags: pymodbus

I've seen several similar issues with no form of response from the other end. For some reason, I am unable to get a response from the slave device.

I'm operating a Windows 10 PC and running Python through VS Code. I'm using a USB to RS485 Serial Converter Cable connected to a UR48483A Wachendorff-Prozesstechnik PID controller. I've double checked the slave address on the device, the baudrate should likewise be correct.

This is the entirety of the code at present;

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
with ModbusClient(method = "rtu", port="COM4", baudrate = 115200, stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8, parity = "N", timeout = 2) as client:
    
    connection = client.connect()
    print(connection)
    result = client.read_coils(address = 0, count = 10, unit = 247)
    print(result)
```

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `read_coils` (0x01) is not supported, try `read_holding_registers` (0x03) or `read_input_registers` (0x04).

You could also try swapping RS485 +/- because naming is inconsistent between manufacturers ([wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485#Signals)).

Comment: Does the 0x03/04 get used as the unit parameter? Am I using the slave address correctly?

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I mean replace `result = client.read_coils(address = 0, count = 10, unit = 247)` with `result = client.read_holding_registers(address = 0, count = 10, unit = 247)`. The slave address looks fine to me.